# Geting error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph while running karate tests with Spring boot application

Tags: java, karate

Getting below error while running karate tests with spring boot application

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.acceptPaths(java.lang.String[])'`

Added below maven karate dependencies -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Added component tests with below code -

> ```
> import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;
> import com.ril.rpos.auth.Application;
> import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
> import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
> import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
> import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
>
> public class ComponentTest {
>     private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
>
>     @BeforeAll
>     public static void setUp() throws InterruptedException {
>         //DB.INSTANCE.resetDB();
>         context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
>     }
>
>     @Karate.Test
>     Karate runTests() {
>         return new Karate().path("classpath:features/api/sampletests.feature");
>     }
>
>     @AfterAll
>     public static void tearDown() {
>         if(context != null) {
>             SpringApplication.exit(context, () -> 0);
>             context.close();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Logback in karate is excluded since it was already on classpath and throwing below while starting sprint application -

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation

What is the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to the "fat jar" and see if that makes a difference. Refer the section "Using the Shaded JAR" [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/database/README.md).

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
  <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
  <version>${karate.version}</version>
  <classifier>all</classifier>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```